# Get first not pushed commit message

Tags: git

How can I get first not pushed git commit message on a branch ?

Suppose I have 3 commits on a branch "new_branch"

```
third_commit
second_commit
first_commit
```

I want to execute one git command to return only the first commit message not the commit id.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "commit name"? Could you please give an example? Within the output of `git log`, which part would you like to get?

Comment: ok, I mean commit message, I will update the question

Comment: If you konw its commit id, `git log --pretty=%B <commit-id>`. If you don't, try `git log --pretty=%B new_branch~2`.

Comment: Care to expain why you have undone my edit to the title? In its present form, it is unfortunately nonsensical as there's no such thing as "unpushed commit" in Git—well, unless you also somehow define how do you define "pushed" commit and how to compare the lines of history containing them (which is not done in the question). So yes, your answer is really about getting the message of a commit which is Nth parent of the tip commit.

Answer (score 1):

If `new_branch` ist checked out and the remote branch is marked as the upstream branch of `new_branch` (either because you got it from the remote or it as marked with `--set-upstream` when pushing) this should work for you:

```
git show --quiet --pretty=%B $(git rev-list @{u}..HEAD | tail -n 1)`
```

`@{u}` references the upstream branch, so rev-list will give you all commits in your local branch, that are not in the remote branch. `tail -n 1` gives you only the lowest (=earliest) of those. `git show` would show that commit, where `--quiet` hides the diff and `--pretty=%B` only prints the commit message of that commit.

If `new_branch` is not checked out you can replace `HEAD` with `new_branch` and `@{u}` with the reference to the remote branch (e.g. `origin/new_branch`). The later one would also help, if the upstream of `new_branch` is not configured.

Answer (score 0):

`git reflog` will show all the commit name.
[see the git page](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References)

Comment: This is not helpful, because it doesn't give me what I need.

Comment: can you elaborate more what exactly you want to see ?